# Wiki or Publishing pages before migrate to SharePoint 2019 modern sites?

Tags: sharepoint-server, modern-experience, modern-pages, modern-team-site

We are using SharePoint 2016 and are going to migrate to SharePoint 2019 in the future. We are creating now wiki pages with some OOTB webparts on the welcome pages of sitecollections. What is better to use now? Wiki pages or publishing pages? I would like to use the type for in the future. So we can migrate easy to modern sites.